# How to check whether the coordinate on the line?

Tags: java

I have this class called Line:

```
 public class Line {
    //p1
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    //p2
    private int x2;
    private int y2;

    /*
     * Constructor initializing first and second point.
    @param _x1 is abscissa of the first point.
    @param _y1 is ordinate of the first point.
    @param _x2 is abscissa of the second point.
    @param _y2 is ordinate of the second point.
    */
    public Line(int _x1, int _y1,int _x2,int _y2)
    {
        //set first point
        x1 = _x1;
        y1 = _y1;

        //set second point
        x2 = _x2;
        y2 = _y2;
    }

    //Function calculate and return slope
    public float getSlope()
    {
        return ((float)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
    }   

    public boolean IsPointOnLine(int x, int y)
    {
        //How do I check if (x;y) on the line?
    }
 }
```

As you can see function contains points p1 and p2.It also contains getSlope funtion that returns slope.

In function IsPointOnLine I need to check wheather passed (x;y) coordinate is on the line(the line defined by two points p1(x1;y1) and p2(x2;y2))?If it on the line I need to return `true` if not return `false`.

Comment: What should the method return?

Comment: It's hard to help when we don't know what you need help with. Please explain what that method should return

Comment: `Create Linear Function` is pretty vague, since a linear function has the form `y = a*x +b` can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MadMatts Matts   , I updated My question please see it.

Comment: Where do you have to return `true` or `false`? You method has a return type of `float`

Comment: So, you actually want a method `boolean includesPoint(int x3, int y3)` that returns true if the given point is on the line, and false otherwise, and not a method `float CreateLinearFunction()`? Starting with the right method signature and return type helps.

Comment: `(y1 - y2) * (x1 - x3) == (y1 - y3) * (x1 - x2)`should do the trick to determine if the 3 points are on the same line or if x_0 == 0: getSlope()*x3 == y3 can also be a valid identifier

Comment: @MadMatts can you explain the trick please?

Comment: transform it like `(y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2) == (y1 - y3)/(x1 - x3)` you see it is like your getSlope equation. if this is true it proofs that the slope between point 1 and point 2 is equal to the slope between point 1 and point 3 and therefor all three points are on the same line

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to pass p3(x3,y3) and configure whether the coordinate on the line then you just need to check whether the slope is same using different coordinates or not.So add this function

```
public boolean coordinatesFallOnLine(int x3, int y3)
    {
        float slope = getSlope();
        float calculatedSlope = (float)(y3-y1)/(x3-x1);
        return slope == calculatedSlope;
    }
```